# Getting CSRF token in external js file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

So I want to enable CSRF protection in my codeigniter app, but this means my js no longer works when its in an external file

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,field,id) 
{

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var segment_3 = pathArray[3];
var save_data = { 
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
                    'field':field,
                    'editedValue':editableObj.innerHTML,
                    'id':id

                };

$.ajax({
    url: segment_3+'/update',
    type: 'POST',
    data:save_data,
    success: function(){
        $(editableObj).addClass('bg-success');
    }        
});
}
```

I tested by copy pasting it into the view file, and it works perfectly fine.
So the problem is that this line

```
'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
```

wont work in an external file? Is there any way to get that working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can store this value to hidden input or any hidden element and then you can access it in external js file..

```
<input type ='hidden' name='what_you_want' id='whatever_you_like' value='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>'>
<input type ='hidden' name='what_you_want1' id='whatever_you_like1' value='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'>
```

and you can get it in js like this

```
var tmp = $('#whatever_you_like').val();
var tmp1 = $('#whatever_you_like1').val();

var save_data = { 
                    tmp: tmp1,
                    'field':field,
                    'editedValue':editableObj.innerHTML,
                    'id':id

                };
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't dangerous in anyway, if say a malicious user onto this page?

Edit:-Never mind just discovered CI does this automatically on forms.

Comment: no because i am just getting php value in external javascript nothing else.. because malicious user onto external javascript that also be case right?

Comment: I was just curious if having the csrf token name & hash displayed in the html was dangerous or not.

Answer (score 0):

Define JS constant in header file like

`var CSRF_NAME = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>'`

`var CSRF_TOKEN = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'`

then just call `CSRF_NAME` or `CSRF_TOKEN` any where in external or inline JS.